# How do I add a button as a menu item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, menuitem

This is probably very easy. I just can't seem to get it done. How do I add a button as a menu item? So far I am only able to add texts. Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_id"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="@string/need_button"/>
     ...
</menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "So far I am only able to add texts"? You may wish to publish screenshots depicting what you are seeing. And bear in mind that `"always"` merely increases the odds that the item will appear in the action bar as a toolbar-style button. There still has to be room for it.

Comment: The line that says `android:title="@string/need_button"` causes a text to be displayed. I need to display a button in that spot.

Comment: @CoteMounyo would an icon suffice? or do you need a button? Practically they are buttons, maybe not technically, but in practice they are. Can you elaborate on more on what you want to achieve, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @LuckyMe thanks for clarifying. I wasn't sure what CommonsWare meant by add an icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `android:icon` to your `<item>`, as right now, there is no icon to be displayed.

Comment: Can the icon ever be a textView? Or must it ever be a drawable?

Comment: @CoteMounyo: If you want the icon *and* text, add `|withText` to the `ifRoom` or `always`. If you want to totally replace the action item with your own `View`, use `android:actionLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have reposted so as not to continue this too long and turn it into multiple questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538218/setting-menu-items-title-appears-as-all-cap-on-android